# What exactly IS the code in a Fastfile

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, fastlane

Doesn't **look** like a straight Ruby class, so what exactly *is* it? One large Ruby "block", some custom metalanguage that gets parsed? Just curious. I know you can use Ruby within a Fastfile; how far does that paradigm reach, can you define classes or functions within a Fastfile or does it have to remain only the 'lanes' concept fastlane supports?

Comment: Just curious. What is fastlane?

Comment: @EricDuminil: there is tag description :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Doesn't look like a straight Ruby class

Not a class, no. But plain ruby nonetheless. With a bit of DSL magic.

What this means is that you're free to define classes or otherwise do anything you want, as long as you still configure fastlane properly (invoke `lane` methods and whatnot).

Comment: I see. And this article helped me understand what you meant by a Ruby DSL: https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html

Comment: This article was useful to me as well: https://fabernovel.github.io/2020-10-19/implementing-fastlane-50-lines-of-code